# auto-filling combobox with parameters from main sub

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I am using userforms to perform different actions on my workbook.
So far I was able to use some code but complexifying my work lead to dead ends.

in sheet code :

```
Public c As Integer, lf As Integer, ld As Integer

Sub main()

    Dim tri1 As Crit1, col1 As ColSel
    Set col1 = New ColSel

    'sheet specific parameters
    ld = 8
    lf = 128

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Load col1
    col1.Show
    c = col1.c

    Set tri1 = New Crit1 'The Problem is here
    tri1.c = c
    tri1.ld = ld
    tri1.lf = lf
    tri1.Show

End Sub
```

***ColSel*** is a userform that will get `c` from the user

```
Option Explicit

Private m_c

Property Get c()
    c = m_c
End Property

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.txt_C1 = "B"
End Sub

Private Sub CmdOK_click()

'validation
    If Me.txt_C1 = "" Then
        MsgBox "please enter a column letter", Title:="Erreur"
    End If
    If IsNumeric(Me.txt_C1) Then
        MsgBox "Only enter letters", Title:="Erreur"
    End If
'transformation en numéro de colonne
m_c = Range(Me.txt_C1.value & "1000").Column

Me.Hide

End Sub


Private Sub CmdCancel_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub
```

***Crit1*** :

```
Option Explicit

Dim mlf As Integer, mld As Integer, mc As Integer

Property Let lf(nlf As Integer)
    mlf = nlf
End Property

Property Let ld(nld As Integer)
    mld = nld
End Property

Property Let c(nc As Integer)
    mc = nc
End Property


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim rng As Range, r As Range

    Set rng = Range(Cells(mld, mc), Cells(mlf, mc))
    For Each r In rng
        addunique r.value 
        'specific sub ensuring only one of each value in combobx
    Next r
End Sub


Sub addunique(value As Variant)

    Dim i As Integer, sortie As Boolean
    Dim inList As Boolean

    inList = False
    If value <> vide Then
        With Me.ComboBox1
            For i = 0 To Me.ComboBox1.ListCount - 1
                If Me.ComboBox1.List(i) = value Then
                    inList = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i

            If Not inList Then
                i = .ListCount - 1
                sortie = False
                While i >= 0 And sortie = False
                    If StrComp(.List(i), value, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                        i = i - 1
                    Else: sortie = True
                    End If
                Wend
                .AddItem value, i + 1
            End If
        End With
    End If

End Sub


Sub CmdOK_click()

    For i = mld To mlf Step 2
        If Cells(i, mc) = Me.ComboBox1 Then
            Rows(i & ":" & i + 1).Hidden = False
        Else:
            Rows(i & ":" & i + 1).Hidden = True
        End If
    Next i
    Unload ColSel
    Unload Me

End Sub


Sub CmdCnl_click()
    Unload ColSel
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

As you can see, in the intialization part of my second userform, I need (for combobox auto completion to have acces to `c`, `lf` and `ld`
My problem is that the initialisation does not let me implement these values in before I get to the point where I need them.

I have tried to go through public variables but no success either.

Comment: I can see `Crit1` Class in your code, where is `ColSel` Class code ?

Comment: Did not put the full code in there to avoid having a too big code part.
Its functionnality is quickly described, the only interest here is to get parameter "c" (it has no other interaction, neither with main nor Crit1).
I can add it if you request (with the rest of Crit 1 code)

Comment: if you can, please upload both classes code

Comment: done, I hope it will help. 
Final version will have much more functions, here is the beginning.

Comment: Your error at the line `Set rng = Range(Cells(mld, mc), Cells(mlf, mc))`, located in `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` in `Crit1`, and it's because `mld` and `mc` are 0.

Comment: any feedback ? did you test the code in my answer below ?

Comment: Sorry, work got me working on other subject, you have a comment on your answer. Thank you for your time btw

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve your error, since you need to get the values of `c` , `lf` and `ld` before the init process, you need to make sure they have unique variable names (currently you have the exact same variables inside your User_Forms code). The next step is to access these `Public` variables on the ***Crit1*** `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` code.

**Main Module Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Pub_c As Integer, Pub_lf As Integer, Pub_ld As Integer ' < -modified the names of the Public variables

Sub main()

    Dim tri1 As Crit1
    Dim col1 As ColSel1

    Set col1 = New ColSel1

    'sheet specific parameters
    Pub_ld = 8
    Pub_lf = 128

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Load col1
    col1.Show
    Pub_c = col1.c ' <-- modifed this line

    Set tri1 = New Crit1
    tri1.Show

End Sub
```

***Crit1* Code** (only modified `UserForm_Initialize`)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim rng As Range, r As Range

    ' added this part : modify properties according to values of Public variabels
    Me.ld = Pub_ld
    Me.lf = Pub_lf
    Me.c = Pub_c

    Set rng = Range(Cells(mld, mc), Cells(mlf, mc))
    For Each r In rng
        addunique r.value
        'specific sub ensuring only one of each value in combobx
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Does not work : shows error "undefined variable" as soon as it hits "Me.ld = Pub_ld"
I respecify that this was working in a module but does not work on specific sheet code.

Comment: @PEagle  did u copy the code in main and the definition of the Public variables ?

Comment: Yes, made all the changes exactly as you did on your answer.